# ubuntu up-to-date but still showing updates

Tags: 16.04, apt, upgrade, updates

I ran the following command to update my ubuntu machine: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade --fix-missing -y

[image: upgrade result]

After installing updates, it still shows the following when I log in:

[image: shown after login]

Can I remove this somehow?

Comment: Run `sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Comment: Doesn't solve this issue.

Comment: What does this mean? Did anything upgrade? And please don't post terminal output as a screenshot. Post it as text.

Comment: Sorry, no it didn't do anything.

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: This must be a minor bug, just ignore it.

Comment: No way I can remove this by hand? Guess it's not there without a reason right?

Answer (score 1):

Message Of The Day (MOTD) is not refreshed each time you login... what you are seeing is normal though incredibly annoying. If after apt update && apt upgrade you see that everything is good to go, your MOTD is simply out of sync.

You can force a MOTD update with the following command.

sudo /usr/lib/update-notifier/update-motd-updates-available --force

Answer (score 0):

cd /etc/update-motd.d

90-updates-available is a script containing a link to a file containing the message. I deleted the file: /var/lib/update-notifier/updates-available. This solved my problem.

Comment: No, you broke your system.

Comment: I did? Tell me how I should have solved it then, please.

Comment: You deleted a file without knowing what part it plays in the software update system. You probably broke the whole update system (try and run Software Updater and see if it works). If you don't know what it does, you shouldn't touch/delete it. You could try using Synaptic to install the missing updates.

Comment: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade runs fine at the moment.